# How to make a brake function for a car pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

i am new to python and i wanted to know how to make the car have a braking function by pressing spacebar. I have put controls to make the car go left right forward and reverse, but slowing down is what i need using the spacebar. I don't know if my code is required to answer the question but here it is anyways.

Thanks

```
import math
import random
import pygame


WHITE = pygame.Color('white')

VEHICLE1 = pygame.Surface((40, 70), pygame.SRCALPHA)
VEHICLE1.fill((130, 180, 20))
#blitting car onto 'rectangle car'
VEHICLE1 = pygame.image.load("YellowLambo.png")
screen.blit(VEHICLE1,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()

VEHICLE2 = pygame.Surface((40, 70), pygame.SRCALPHA)
VEHICLE2.fill((200, 120, 20))
#blitting computer's car
VEHICLE2 = pygame.image.load("RedLambo.png")
screen.blit(VEHICLE2,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()

BACKGROUND = pygame.Surface((1280, 800))
BACKGROUND.fill((127, 69, 2))
BACKGROUND = pygame.image.load("track2.png").convert()
screen.blit(BACKGROUND,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()


class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


class VehicleSprite(Entity):
    MAX_FORWARD_SPEED = 10
    MAX_REVERSE_SPEED = 2
    ACCELERATION = 0.05
    TURN_SPEED = 0.000000000001


    def __init__(self, image, position):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.src_image = image
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=position)
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(position)
        self.velocity = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.speed = self.direction = 0
        self.k_left = self.k_right = self.k_down = self.k_up = 0

    def update(self, time):
        # SIMULATION
        self.speed += self.k_up + self.k_down
        # To clamp the speed.
        self.speed = max(-self.MAX_REVERSE_SPEED,
                         min(self.speed, self.MAX_FORWARD_SPEED))

        # Degrees sprite is facing (direction)
        self.direction += (self.k_right + self.k_left)
        rad = math.radians(self.direction)
        self.velocity.x = -self.speed*math.sin(rad)
        self.velocity.y = -self.speed*math.cos(rad)
        self.position += self.velocity
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.src_image, self.direction)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.position)


class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)


def game_loop():
    bike = VehicleSprite(VEHICLE1, rect.center)
    ball = VehicleSprite(VEHICLE2, rect.center)

    bike_group = pygame.sprite.Group(bike)
    ball_group = pygame.sprite.Group(ball)
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(bike_group, ball_group)
    background = Background(BACKGROUND, [0, 0])

    camera = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
    done = False

    while not done:
        time = clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # Bike Input (Player 1)
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    bike.k_right = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    bike.k_left = 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    bike.k_up = 2
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    bike.k_down = -2


                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    bike.k_right = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    bike.k_left = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    bike.k_up = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    bike.k_down = 0


        camera -= bike.velocity

        #screen.blit(background.image, background.rect)
        all_sprites.update(time)

        screen.fill(WHITE)

        screen.blit(background.image, background.rect.topleft+camera)

        for sprite in all_sprites:
            screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft+camera)


        pygame.display.flip()


game_loop()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: If you have figured out how to make the car go left and right, what's the problem with braking?

Comment: If the car can accelerate well, then you can just do the same code but type the values and everything just the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `self.k_break` attribute, set it to `True` when the player breaks and then decrease the `self.speed` if it's greater than 0 and increase it if it's less than 0. Use `max` and `min`, so that it stops at 0.

```
def update(self, time):
    self.speed += self.k_up + self.k_down
    if self.k_break:
        if self.speed > 0:
            self.speed = max(0, self.speed-0.5)
        elif self.speed < 0:
            self.speed = min(0, self.speed+0.5)
```